# Retrieve data from asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net, gridview, dataadapter

What is wrong in this program?? 
    it shows error in `da.Fill(dt);`. This program is for searching record from DataBase by Name.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public partial class NameSearch : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public SqlConnection con = new 

       SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].   
       ConnectionString);

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
    }
    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from case1 where     
        Name="+txtSearchName.Text,con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet dt = new DataSet();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Text` in commandtype instead of `StoredProcedure`..Use parameterized query to avoid sql injection

```
string name=txtSearchName.Text;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from case1 where Name=@name",con);
cmd .Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
da.Fill(dt);
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from case1 where     
    Name='"+txtSearchName.Text + "'",con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds= new DataSet();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    da.Fill(ds, "FooTable");
    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["FooTable"];;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
```